# HTML5 - Horizontally aligning Image and Table inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, inline, positioning

I am using Bootstrap and i want to align an image and a table "side-by-side" in the same column.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="col-md-10" style="width: 100%"> 
       <img src="#"  class="img-responsive pull-left pro-page-pro-image">
        <div class="container">
       <table class="table table-responsive pull-right pro-page-contact-details-table">
         <tbody>
 <!---the table has 12 rows in total -->
            <tr>
              <td>MEMBER SINCE</td>
              <td>2007</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Suburb</td>
             <td>Fourways, Randburg</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
 .pro-page-pro-image {
  display:inline;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 11%; 
  margin-right: 11%; 
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
 .pro-page-contact-details-table {
  display: inline;
  }
```

The classes `.table` and `.table-responsive` are standard bootstrap classes. At the moment in the browser the table is positioned directly below the image (both left aligned) and despite trying numerous things I can't get them to align side-by-side.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-10" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="img-responsive pull-left pro-page-pro-image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <table class="table table-responsive pull-right pro-page-contact-details-table">
        <tbody>
          TABLE HERE
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you need to use a ROW and in the row u define the  columns. 6+6 = the 12 max so it should align now. and if u use container. it will use the full width of the screen so then you cant allign stuff.

Comment: Thank you H. Brendan your suggestions have fixed my problem. Appreciated.